# Locate devices that can move among multiple connections

Tags: led

I don’t know if this is even doable, but the idea is to have a large board with many (500+) locations where I objects can connect, each object having a single LED, and be able to illuminate the LED on any object, no matter where it is connected on the board.  So the requirement is that the objects can be moved to any of the connections on the board and and that the board can have any number if it’s connections occupied.

It seems obvious that each object would have to be able to identify itself and that each connection would have to be able to supply both a signal both ways and and provide power to light the LED.  On the code side, I’d need to be able to iterate through the connections and identify the desired object by some unique identifier and send a signal to turn the LED on and off.  I’m a .Net developer with little knowledge of electronics, but I’m willing to learn if it’s possible to do this.  I haven’t been able to find any arduino examples similar enough to provide some idea of where to start.  I don’t know if this is something that can even be done with Arduino or what components would be required if it is possible.

I’d appreciate any guidance on how this could be done or even suggestions as to what might be a better approach toward finding the guidance necessary to build this.

Comment: Please add some more requirements. Examples, max number of devices connected, power limit, total cost of device, more on the algorithm when connecting, timing of algorithm, respons time, etc. And last but not least, budget of project and max cost of board.

Comment: what is "the object" and what signal should it get? is it only some plastic shape with a LED that should be turned on and off?

Comment: are the objects addressable? . .. are the locations addressable?

Comment: Does the object (or main controller) need to know where it's pushed in? Your question is way too vague, but I was thinking of using audio sockets for the 500 locations and an audio jacks attached to the objects. Some of these jacks have ways to pass though a signal if no jack is inserted. So you could use Addressable LEDs in the objects, and have the sockets wired so the data goes to the led if the jack is inserted, or pass though if not.

Comment: The "objects" could be anything - even a block of wood.  Anything that would serve as an object upon which I could mount whatever components that would allow me to   flash an LED on the object no matter where it was located on the board.  I would need to have boards of various sizes, each having a different number of potential locations in a grid layout upon which these objects could be placed and moved from one location on the board to another.  I would need some means of being able to flash the LED of a specific block no matter where that block was attached on the board.

Comment: is LED "the object" or "the object" can have two LEDs and a temperature sensor. do you want to create a LED matrix or a network of sensor nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is awfully vague.

There is a protocol called I2C that's commonly used for microcontrollers. It's a serial bus that has a data line, a clock line, power, and ground. That might meet your needs.

Each device on an I2C bus is supposed to have a unique address. You send commands to it using that address, and it doesn't matter where it is located physically.

I2C is designed to be a chain, and each device has 2 connectors that pass the connection on to the next device on the chain.

I2C also uses a byte address, so you could only have 255 unique devices.

Comment: This sounds promising except that I would need more than 255 potential addresses.  I would need to be able to have a boards with grids of up to 100 columns and 50 rows where objects could be attached, so such a board would have to be able to support up to 5,000 objects with LEDs that could each be individually flashed no matter where they were on the board.